# Importing xml into excel

Tags: xml, excel

I'm trying to import xml files into excel, some 40,000 files so that each of them are entered as single entry into my database, meaning i'd have 40,000 rows with the given elements contained within the documents (which are all the same). However when I add just one xml file into excel, it repeats a lot of the data so that one file ends up taking about 100 rows. It's doing this because some elements have multiple values, but I want all those to somehow be contained in one cell in a drop box like manner.

```
<accession>HMDB00001</accession> 
-<secondary_accessions> 
<accession>HMDB04935</accession> 
<accession>HMDB06703</accession> 
<accession>HMDB06704</accession> 
</secondary_accessions>
```

Is there a way of importing the xml files into excel so that the values for some of the elements are somehow placed into one cell rather than multiple cells?

Comment: can u do programming? it should be relatively easy if u use apache poi package. so u can add all ur elements to a set(no multiples)

Comment: I'm afraid my programming abilities is quite little, but I can always give it a go

Comment: well I suppose I can put you in right direction if you ever considered doing some programming: u'll need: 1- "xml parser" 2-"excel" library(e.g. apache poi). idea is simple parse the tags you want from your xml. add them into sets(so no multiple data will be added) then using excel library to add data and create an file

Comment: Alternatively you can simply use this link : [http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/delete-duplicate-rows-from-a-list-in-excel-HA001034626.aspx)

Comment: Problem is I would have to do it 40,000 times for the different entries. I'll give the apache poi package a go

Comment: yeah working with such large data requires a bit of programming, it makes life easier :)

Comment: So I'm still rather confused about this approach haha. Where would I go about downloading apache poi and xml parser?

Comment: hmm, I'm a java developer, there is a xml parser library already install if u get java jdk. and apache poi package can be found in [here](http://poi.apache.org/)